# Iteration using reflection through Object constants in an interface

Tags: java, reflection, iteration

I was trying to implement something like enum by myself. While i was trying to iterate my constant objects i came across using reflection and i stumbled upon [java.lang.reflect.Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) . So here is my scenario. I have an entity class for holding a pair of String constants

```
public class ConstantEntity {

    private String constantName;
    private String constantDesc;

    ConstantEntity(String name, String desc) {
        this.constantName = name;
        this.constantDesc = desc;
    }

    public String constantName() {
        return this.constantName;
    }

    public String constantDesc() {
        return this.constantDesc;
    }

}
```

And I have a interface where i create the constants using the entity

```
public interface MyConstantsPool { 

    public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_ONE = new ConstantEntity("bla1", "11");
    public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_TWO = new ConstantEntity("bla2", "12");
    public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_THREE  = new ConstantEntity("bla3", "13");


}
```

And i am trying to consume and iterate through these constants using

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ConsumeConstants {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Field[] fields = MyConstantsPool.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

            Object myConstant = fields[i];
            ConstantEntity typeSafeEnum = (ConstantEntity) myConstant ;
            System.out.println(" The name: "
                    + ((ConstantEntity) typeSafeEnum).constantName());
            System.out.println(" The description: "
                    + ((ConstantEntity) typeSafeEnum).constantDesc());

        }
    }
}
```

I went through the documentation, but i couldn't grasp the idea behind Field. Am I completely wrong in the understanding of using reflection? When do we use Field? And what is the proper way to iterate through all the Object constants in the interface?

**NOTE:** I am using java 1.4; So i have to use basic java features to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Field` is an accessor which lets you do set and get operations and also do examination, like discover the type or modifiers of the field at run-time.

> And what is the proper way to iterate through all the Object constants in the interface?

If you want to iterate all the `static ConstantEntity` fields, you could use something like this:

```
Field[] fields = MyConstantsPool.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    Field f = fields[i];
    if ( ConstantEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())
            && Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) ) {
        ConstantEntity constant =
            (ConstantEntity) f.get(null);
    }
}
```

> Am I completely wrong in the understanding of using reflection?

From the mistake in your code, trying to cast `myConstant` directly to `ConstantEntity`, at least partially. You have to call `get` to actually retrieve the value held in the field. The `Field` object itself is just an accessor.

You may also see [*"What is reflection and why is it useful?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37628/2891664)

---

Also, Java 1.4, really??? That's more than 10 years out of date.

Comment: Interfaces can't have non-static fields so `Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()` is probably redundant (unless I misunderstood your idea).

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, you're right that checking the modifier here is more or less redundant. My code example is just intended to be a bit more general.

Answer (score 1):

you just made simple error,
you grab `Field` and tried to cast it to your class `ConstantEntity`,

you need to get value from field:

```
 Object myConstant = fields[i].get(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Reflection you can inspect the fields (member variables) of classes and get / set them at runtime.

> Given an instance of a class, it is possible to use reflection to set
>   the values of fields in that class. This is typically done only in
>   special circumstances when setting the values in the usual way is not
>   possible. **Because such access usually violates the design intentions
>   of the class, it should be used with the utmost discretion.**

So a Class object can be used to obtain a Field object for a declared public, **declared protected, or declared private field.**

But, also in your case it could be useful for the 'design intention' of your interface.

Comment: @Radiodef "I went through the documentation, but i couldn't grasp the idea behind Field. Am I completely wrong in the understanding of using reflection? When do we use Field?"
I interpreted the question as: "why use reflection? when is useful? what is goal?"
Was I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use arrays instead of reflection?

```
public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_ONE = new ConstantEntity("bla1", "11");
public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_TWO = new ConstantEntity("bla2", "12");
public static final ConstantEntity CONSTANT_THREE  = new ConstantEntity("bla3", "13");

public static final ConstantEntity[] CONSTANTS = {
    CONSTANT_ONE,
    CONSTANT_TWO,
    CONSTANT_THREE
};
```